# How can I get all results in ReactiveList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, elasticsearch, react-native, reactivesearch

I've tried to use on all data but it doesn't work since I can get only the number of results as stated in the 'size' parameter. Here part of my code.

```
<ReactiveList
  componentId="results"
  dataField="original_title"
  size={1}
  showResultStats={true}
  pagination={true}
  react={{
    and: "searchbox"
  }}
  onAllData={this.onAllData}
/>

onAllData(shops) {
  let result = null;
  if (shops !== null) {
    console.log(shops.length);
    result = shops.map((marker) => (
      <ListItem>
        <Thumbnail square size={80} source={{ uri: 'https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff' }} />
        <Body>
        <Text>{marker.name}</Text>
        <Text note>{marker.dis}</Text>
        </Body>
      </ListItem>
    ))
    return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can go about this problem:

## Rendering all results with infinite loading

`onAllData` will give the number of results specified in the `size` prop. Usually, its not a good idea to set a very high `size` since it will take more time fetching and rendering the results. A good alternative for this is to use infinite scrolling by setting the `pagination` prop to `false` and setting a value in `size` prop which tells the component how many results to fetch when you reach the end of the list.

## Fetching all results using scroll API

### tl;dr [**Demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/849x3rj72l)

> **Note**
>
> This answer uses reactivesearch for web (for demonstration) but you can use the same props in reactivesearch-native since the API is same.

The above approach works fine if you're only interested in rendering the results. But if you wish to fetch all the results for the current query, you can use the [**scroll**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) API from Elasticsearch. You can use `ReactiveList` to get the current query and then use it together with the scroll API.

For this purpose, you can make use of the `onQueryChange` prop on `ReactiveList`:

First specify an `onQueryChange` prop on the `ReactiveList` which receives the previous and current query as parameters:

```
onQueryChange={(prev, next) => ...}
```

This function will be invoked each time the query is changed so you can write a logic to fetch the hits for the current query (received in the `next` parameter) whenever required.

A scroll API call returns the results in the following format:

```
{
  "_scroll_id": "DnF1ZXJ5VGhlbkZldGNoAgAAAAClGlY4FlotbmJJZXA0U09lMlZFMUNyQ3M2M0EAAAAApRpWORZaLW5iSWVwNFNPZTJWRTFDckNzNjNB",
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 2,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 9407,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "good-books-ds",
        "_type": "good-books-ds",
        "_id": "5676",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "authors": "Arthur C. Clarke, Gentry Lee",
          "average_rating": 3.76,
          "average_rating_rounded": 4,
          "books_count": 48,
          "id": 5676,
          "image": "https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1375814957l/112518.jpg",
          "image_medium": "https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1375814957m/112518.jpg",
          "isbn": "1857230213",
          "language_code": "eng",
          "original_publication_year": 1991,
          "original_series": "Rama",
          "original_title": "The Garden of Rama (Rama, #3)",
          "ratings_count": 16389,
          "title": "The Garden of Rama (Rama, #3)"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "good-books-ds",
        "_type": "good-books-ds",
        "_id": "5681",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "authors": "Darren Shan",
          "average_rating": 4.22,
          "average_rating_rounded": 4,
          "books_count": 52,
          "id": 5681,
          "image": "https://s.gr-assets.com/assets/nophoto/book/111x148-bcc042a9c91a29c1d680899eff700a03.png",
          "image_medium": "https://s.gr-assets.com/assets/nophoto/book/111x148-bcc042a9c91a29c1d680899eff700a03.png",
          "isbn": "",
          "language_code": "",
          "original_publication_year": 2003,
          "original_series": "Cirque Du Freak",
          "original_title": "Killers of the Dawn (Cirque Du Freak, #9)",
          "ratings_count": 18194,
          "title": "Killers of the Dawn (Cirque Du Freak, #9)"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "good-books-ds",
        "_type": "good-books-ds",
        "_id": "5683",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "authors": "Laura Joffe Numeroff, Felicia Bond",
          "average_rating": 4.16,
          "average_rating_rounded": 4,
          "books_count": 13,
          "id": 5683,
          "image": "https://s.gr-assets.com/assets/nophoto/book/111x148-bcc042a9c91a29c1d680899eff700a03.png",
          "image_medium": "https://s.gr-assets.com/assets/nophoto/book/111x148-bcc042a9c91a29c1d680899eff700a03.png",
          "isbn": "60278684",
          "language_code": "",
          "original_publication_year": 2000,
          "original_series": "",
          "original_title": "If You Take a Mouse to the Movies",
          "ratings_count": 17938,
          "title": "If You Take a Mouse to the Movies"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "good-books-ds",
        "_type": "good-books-ds",
        "_id": "5685",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "authors": "Orson Scott Card, James Cameron",
          "average_rating": 4.06,
          "average_rating_rounded": 4,
          "books_count": 15,
          "id": 5685,
          "image": "https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1225165505l/40289.jpg",
          "image_medium": "https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1225165505m/40289.jpg",
          "isbn": "99690608",
          "language_code": "eng",
          "original_publication_year": 1989,
          "original_series": "",
          "original_title": "The Abyss",
          "ratings_count": 16318,
          "title": "The Abyss"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "good-books-ds",
        "_type": "good-books-ds",
        "_id": "5687",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "authors": "Katarina Bivald, Alice Menzies",
          "average_rating": 3.56,
          "average_rating_rounded": 4,
          "books_count": 63,
          "id": 5687,
          "image": "https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1452107441l/25573977.jpg",
          "image_medium": "https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1452107441m/25573977.jpg",
          "isbn": "149262344X",
          "language_code": "eng",
          "original_publication_year": 2013,
          "original_series": "",
          "original_title": "Läsarna i Broken Wheel rekommenderar",
          "ratings_count": 14571,
          "title": "The Readers of Broken Wheel Recommend"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The value received as `_scroll_id` can be passed to the scroll API to fetch the next set of results and so on till the number of hits is zero.

> **Note**
>
> If your cluster has a lot of data, its not a good idea to run this logic to fetch all the results every time the query changes. You can add a condition to limit the number of results fetched or store the current query in state and only fetch all the results when required.

Here's an example on how you can implement this with `ReactiveList`. In the example I'm fetching the results each time the query changes but you can modify it to fetch results conditionally instead:

In your `render` function:

```
<ReactiveList
  ...
  size={10}
  onQueryChange={this.handleQueryChange}
/>
```

Here's how the `handleQueryChange` function can look like. This will give you all the results for the current query:

```
handleQueryChange = async (prev, next) => {
    // avoid fetching the results for match_all query since dataset is large
    if (next && !next.query.match_all) {
      console.log('Fetching all results for query:', next);

      // modify the query size here if needed (currently it is 10)
      // initial url to obtain scroll id is different

      const initialResults = await this.fetchResults(next, url);

      // keep scrolling till hits are present
      // NOTE: careful if you've a lot of results,
      // in that case you might want to add a condition to limit calls to scroll API

      const scrollResults = await this.fetchScrollResults({
        scroll: "1m",
        scroll_id: initialResults._scroll_id
      });

      // combine the two to get all results
      // concat hits from initialResults with hits from scrollResults

      const allResults = initialResults.hits.hits.concat(scrollResults);
      console.log(`${allResults.length} results found:`, allResults);
    }
};
```

Its using two functions for fetching the results initially and later with the `scroll_id`. The endpoints for both are different, which you can find in the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/849x3rj72l). Here's how the first `fetchResults` looks like:

```
fetchResults = (query, api) => {
    return fetch(api, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Basic ${btoa(credentials)}`
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(query)
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
};
```

The `fetchScrollResults` will use the scroll API to fetch results till the hits obtained are 0.

```
fetchScrollResults = async query => {
    const res = await this.fetchResults(query, scrollUrl);
    const { hits } = res.hits;
    if (hits.length) {
        return [
            ...hits,
            ...(await this.fetchScrollResults({
                scroll: "1m",
                scroll_id: res._scroll_id
            }))
        ];
    }
    return [];
};
```

Check the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/849x3rj72l), results will appear in the console.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How about after I have get all result from reactiveList. If I want to save it to the state(just 20 results at most), where can I call setState function? Currently, I set state in a function that is called in the render. So I will face infinite loop of setting state. How can I solve it....?

Comment: You can set them in state where I've logged them out in the `handleQueryChange` function. Also, if you're only interested in 20 results at max, you don't even need the scroll API. Just use the `fetchResults` method adding a `size` key of  `20` in the query received as the `next` parameter.

Comment: What should I type if in `Basic ${btoa(credentials)}` if I have a credentials like Z8qef2A4rR0:de9wfqqefweb4-84a0-40a5-9937-b54ce843356 (for example)

Comment: You'll have to put the entire thing in as credentials. Check the demo link where I'm doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a key that identify unique components and you also need to wrap element inside function. If function is called properly and your array have elements this should work.

```
onAllData(shops) {
 let result = null;
 if (shops !== null) {
   console.log(shops.length);
   result = shops.map((marker,index) => { return (
      <ListItem key={index}>
        <Thumbnail square size={80} source={{ uri: 'https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff' }} />
        <Body>
          <Text>{marker.name}</Text>
          <Text note>{marker.dis}</Text>
        </Body>
     </ListItem>
    )})
   return result;
}
```